# Fetch commens from a specific post

Tags: php, comments

I'm trying to fetch the comments from a specific post to show them elsewhere in the website.
This is the code I use to fetch the comments of the **current** post; how do I edit it so that it fetches the comments from another post referenced by id?

```
<?php
if (have_comments()) {
    ?>
    <h3 class="comments-title">
        <?php
        echo '';
        ?>
    </h3> 
    <ol class="comments-list">
        <?php
        wp_list_comments(
            array(
                'style' => 'ol',
                'format' => 'html5',
                'avatar_size' => '100'
            )
        );
        ?>
    </ol>
    <div class="comments-navigation">
        <div class='previous-comments-link'><?php previous_comments_link(); ?></div>
        <div class='next-comments-link'><?php next_comments_link(); ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you pull the comments of a post via the id and then edit the returned content info of the post. You will be required to add your CSS and html to style the comments.

```
    $args = array(
    'author_email' => '',
    'author__in' => '',
    'author__not_in' => '',
    'include_unapproved' => '',
    'fields' => '',
    'ID' => '',
    'comment__in' => '',
    'comment__not_in' => '',
    'karma' => '',
    'number' => '',
    'offset' => '',
    'orderby' => '',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'parent' => '',
    'post_author__in' => '',
    'post_author__not_in' => '',
    //Post id here
    'post_id' => '162',
    ////////////////////////
    'post__in' => '',
    'post__not_in' => '',
    'post_author' => '',
    'post_name' => '',
    'post_parent' => '',
    'post_status' => '',
    'post_type' => '',
    'status' => 'all',
    'type' => '',
    'type__in' => '',
    'type__not_in' => '',
    'user_id' => '',
    'search' => '',
    'count' => false,
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
    'meta_query' => '',
    'date_query' => null, // See WP_Date_Query
);

$comments = get_comments($args);
foreach($comments as $comment) :
     // echos the comment author and the content, you can use any of the above tags to create the displayed data but will need to custom the html/CSS style
    echo($comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment->comment_content. '<br />');
endforeach;


        ?>
    <div class="comments-navigation">
        <div class='previous-comments-link'><?php previous_comments_link(); ?></div>
        <div class='next-comments-link'><?php next_comments_link(); ?></div>
    </div>
    <?php
```